# need "ensure dependency is up to date"

Tags: shake-build-system

I was watching Neil's [discussing shake](https://youtu.be/xYCPpXVlqFM?t=241) at ICFP. He mentions in the talk that the **need** function ensures that the dependency is "up to date". What does this mean exactly? Below is the code used in the talk:

```hs
"Foo.o" *> \_ -> do
   need ["Foo.c"]
   ...
   ...
   system' "gcc" ["-c", "Foo.c"]
```

Does this mean that the Shake framework expects there to be a "rule" on how to build "Foo.c", and will run that rule when figuring out if it needs to re-run the rule for building "Foo.o"? If that is the case, does Shake in essence have a map from File to Rule? What happens when my dependency is a file that simply exists on my system? If Shake is not used to generate it, and I use `need ["Somefile.txt"]`, no rule will exist for how to build "Somefile.txt". Will Shake crash? At the root of it all, we have to start from some files that already exist.

P.S. I am new to build systems and to Shake; any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency is "up to date" if all its dependencies are up to date, and it has been run with those dependencies in their current value. But the important point in this question seems to be that `Foo.o` in Shake can refer to two things:

- There can be a rule `"Foo.o" *>` which runs some commands, probably depending on source files, and produces an output file `Foo.o`.
- If there are no rules to produce `Foo.o`, then Shake assumes `Foo.o` is a source file. At the leaves there must be files that are source files.

You can see this in the error message Shake produces:

```
$ shake shakeOptions $ action $ need ["hello.txt"]
Error, file does not exist and no rule available:
  hello.txt
```

The fact that rules are named after the file they produced, and the absence of a rule implies it's a source file is shared with build systems like Make. However, this property is different from build systems like Buck/Bazel where targets and sources have distinct namespaces.

Comment: Thank you Neil for taking the time to answer my question. Because I was so unfamiliar with build systems, I took the time to read Chapter 1 and Chapter 2 of the GNU make manual. This gave me a stronger mental model of what build systems in general are. I believe we are mis-using shake at work (though I say that cautiously given my neophyte understanding). At any rate, your response answered my question, though I wish I would have read the make docs first to save you the time. Thank you!